# Update one table using self-join for other table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I have two tables. I need to update the records of the 1st table performing a join with the 2nd table. But in the 2nd table I also have to put a self join.

```
UPDATE [T2] 
SET T2.NAME = T1.NAME 
FROM [TABLE2] T2 
JOIN [TABLE1] T1 ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
JOIN [TABLE1] T3 ON T1.RECORDTYPE = T3. RECORDTYPE
```

The purpose is to perform a self-join and update the other table.

Comment: What is the problem with the query in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
UPDATE T2 
    SET T2.NAME = T1.NAME 
FROM T2 
JOIN T1 
    ON T2.ID = T1.ID 
    AND T2.RECORDTYPE = T1.RECORDTYPE;
```

Comment: Actually Need to Merge Two rows based on Record Type 1 or 2. Means I have to Update few fields for Record Type 1 Record from Record Type 2 Field. eg. Take City & Country only from Record Type 2 field. Both Records have same Id. So the result will be single row for same id.

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/-SXv3GHO with sample data that Illustrates the problem and update your post with url and expected result. As of now it is kind d of hard to guess what you are trying to do